# How to render viewcontroller in this way using navigation controller

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have 3 view stacks namely MyHomeViewController, MySubViewController, MyReplyListViewController.

Now the MyHomeViewController is the root view. and when i give back from MySubViewController it takes me to MyHomeViewController.as like and when i give back from MyReplyListViewController it takes me to MySubViewController using navigation controller

So, `MyHomeViewController -> MySubViewController -> MyReplyListViewController`

Now what i want is , when user received a new mail in the app.

When user launching the app and if he has received a new reply, i want to show the MyReplyListViewController first, from there when i give back it has to take me to MySubViewController.
from there when i give back it has to take me to MyHomeViewController

> MyReplyListViewController ->
>   MySubViewController ->
>   MyHomeViewController

This has to happen only once when he has received a new reply.otherwise it has to behave asusaul.

I am trying to accomplish this but no luck

Thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by using the [`UINaviationController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `viewControllers` property and `setViewControllers` method,

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers;
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

**UPDATED:**

For the below controllers.

```
MyReplyListViewController -> MySubViewController -> MyHomeViewController
```

You need to create and array of viewControllers in the reverse order shown above.

```
NSArray* myControllerArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootViewController, subViewController, replyViewController, nil];
```

set it as new stack of navigation.

```
[myNavigationController setViewControllers:myControllerArray animated:NO];
```

Now go directly to your `MyReplyListViewController`.

```
 [myNavigationController popToViewController:replyViewController animated:YES]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. can you show me an example to do this.  sorry for being dump